# Add artifacts to a build programatically?

Tags: tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I've gone through all the documentation on the REST Api: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions

There doesn't seem to be any way to add a build artifact using the REST Api.

Is there another way to do this? or any way to add links to the build summary. I just want a link to a network share folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable Artifacts in the build summary. It's visible only when you have a **Publish Artifacts build step** in the build definition.

Detail ways please refer this blog: [Manage Artifacts with TFS Build vNext](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/06/30/manage-artifacts-with-tfs-build-vnext/)

Comment: This doesn't really solve my problem. What I'm looking for is a concrete example on how to create links under artifacts without using the publish build step -> It's too limited.

Comment: Except that build step, you can't directly add the links in the build summary. Cause the customization of build summary is not support for now. Since vNext web-based build system not like the old XAML build system. Customization  are rarely.